# How can I change the title/contents of a modal dialog using ActionButton?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the contents (e.g. title) of a modal dialog using an Action Button. So, every time I press a location the title/ID of that location will appear, whereas when I press the Action Button, "All locations" appears in the title. How can I do this? Thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
data <- PlantGrowth
data$Lat <- runif(nrow(data), 40, 41)
data$Lon <- runif(nrow(data), -1, 3)
data <- rbind(data[1,], data[11,])

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("map", height="100vh"),
  absolutePanel(style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px",
                top = 10, left = 10, width = 300, height = "auto",
                actionButton("button", "Show all data")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent({input$map_marker_click
                input$button}, {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = input$map_marker_click$id 
          # title = ifelse(" - Input Button Is Pressed -", "All locations", input$map_marker_click$id)
        )
      )
  })
  
  output$map<-
    renderLeaflet({
      plot.map <-
        leaflet(
          data = data, options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = F)
        ) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addCircleMarkers(
          lat = ~ Lat, lng = ~ Lon,
          weight = 1,
          layerId = ~ group,
          fillOpacity = 0.8,
          color = "black",
          opacity = 0.7,
          options = markerOptions(riseOnHover = TRUE))
      return(plot.map)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a reactive value for the title:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Title <- reactiveVal("initial title")

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    Title("All locations")
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    Title(paste0("location ", input$map_marker_click$id)
  }) 

  observeEvent(list(input$map_marker_click, input$button), {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = Title() 
        )
      )
  })

  ......
```